# Magento2 - Add Custom fields block after shipping method

Tags: magento2, php, onepage-checkout, shipping-methods

Want to add custom fields after shipping method at Magento 2 checkout page. I have created custom module with checkout_index_index.xml and able to add custom fields block at after shipping address with `<item name="before-form" xsi:type="array">` but i want it after shipping method.

When customer select shipping method this block show and hide to provide more information about selected shipping method

Find Image below for more information.

[image]

Comment: Please try: https://www.dckap.com/blog/creating-custom-fields-using-magento-2-ui-components/ and https://ranasohel.me/2015/11/28/how-to-add-custom-field-to-shipping-address-form-in-magento-2-onepage-checkout/

Comment: @Pravin Did you get ? please share

Comment: Hello
You found any solution ?

Comment: @sumeetbajaj well I used paid extension for that.

Comment: @Pravin now i do not need thank for reply

Comment: @Pravin Can you please provide paid extension URL?